# How to check sim is active or not in android

Tags: android

please tell me is their is any way to check whether a sim is active or not. I know I can do this by using telephony manager but I dont know which method of telephonymnager is helpfull. I tried many but didnt get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for detecting if the sim is available

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)     getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
        switch (simState) {
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                // do something
                break;
        }
```

Comment: please tell me in this differnt states which state shows that a sim is active.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
            switch (simState) {
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                    // do something
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: please tell me in this differnt states which state shows that a sim is active.

Comment: case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                    // do something
                    break;

Comment: In this different cases which case matches the situation when a sim is newly purchased and it is not active for some hours.